# move files to a subdirectory based on filename with spaces

Tags: linux, bash, macos, command-line, terminal

The objective of this script will be to create a directory based on filename content. The filenames looks like this:

- "foo-foo bar-bar-bar1 5644.jpg"
- "foo-foo bar-bar-bar1 5648.jpg" >> /foo-foo bar-bar-bar1
- "foo-foo bar-bar-bar2   7644.jpg"
- "foo-foo bar-bar-bar2   7648.jpg" >> /foo-foo bar-bar-bar2

I want to be able to create a folder named "foo-foo bar-bar-bar1" and so forth for all files in directory. (There are hundreds of directories to create) and put all files with that extension in it.

The problem is that there are spaces and not "_" between the filename extensions. And also, there are multiple spaces between some of the file names.
How can I start going about solving this? I am working on a mac if that helps.

Comment: For the filenames with multiple spaces, do you always move to the directory name made up by all characters before the **last** space?

Comment: Yes!
Sorry for not presenting my issue across correctly. Maybe I am wrong in thinking too..
I am looking for this part of the file extension as a variable:
> **foo-foo bar-bar-bar1a** 
> **foo-foo arb-arb-arb1d**
> **foo-foo abr-abr-abr1e**

I need extension-2, which is random, moved into the directory based on "extension-1 extension-2". The third part is meaningless for organization.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit unclear as to whether your directory name is made up of all characters before the *last* space, your comment helped somewhat, but the *extension-1*, *extension-2* explanation still leaves a bit of uncertainty, but I think we are communicating.

To create a directory, based on everything contained in the filename up to the last space, you can use a simple *parameter expansion with substring removal*. For example, to remove everything from the right, up to (and including) the final space, you would use `dname="${file% *}"` (where `dname` is the resulting directory name to move the file to). Example:

```
file="foo-foo bar-bar-bar1 5648.jpg"
dname="${file% *}"
```

Now `dname` contains: `"foo-foo bar-bar-bar1"`

(**note:** the parameter expansion with `#` trims from the *left* and `%` trims from the right. `##` trims to the last occurrence from the left, while `#` only trims to the first occurrence. `%` works the same way from the opposite direction)

Then simply move the file to `dname`, You can use *process substitution* (using a `find` command to search for all `.jpg` files below the current directory, and creating the new set of directories in the presented directory as well with a simple:

```
while read file; do
    fname="${file##*/}"   ## strip path information, leaving filename
    dname="${fname% *}"   ## get all chars before the last space
    mkdir -p "$dname"     ## create the directory (no error if it exists)
                          #  (add -i to be prompted if dir exists)
    mv "$file" "$dname"   ## move the file to the new directory
done < <(find . -type f -name "*.jpg")
```

You can append to `dname` (or further parse parse `file`) to put the directories somewhere other than in the present directory.

Also note, if you want to further parse the filename so the file you move is `"5648.jpg"` instead of the full `"foo-foo bar-bar-bar1 5648.jpg"`, you simply use something similar to:

```
finalname="${fname##* }"
```

Then your move would be:

```
mv "$file" "$dname/$finalname"
```

Let me know if you have any problems.

---

**Using Last Space Separate Segment as Directory Name (ext-2)**

If we are taking `"cc-19 a-18-1a 6790.jpg"` and moving the file to the `"a-18-1a"` directory, then your series of parsing the filename returned by `find` would be as follows:

```
while read file; do
    fname="${file##*/}"   ## strip path information, leaving filename
    dname="${fname% *}"   ## get all chars before the last space
    dname="${dname##* }"  ## trim ext-1, leaving ext-2
    mkdir -p "$dname"     ## create the directory (no error if it exists)
                          #  (add -i to be prompted if dir exists)
    mv "$file" "$dname"   ## move the file to the new directory
done < <(find . -type f -name "*.jpg")
```

This will move `"cc-19 a-18-1a 6790.jpg"` into `"./a-18-1a"`.

If you there is still a communication problem, just drop another comment.

Comment: Looks good, although I'd recommend using `mv -i` to avoid overwriting files if something weird happens and there's a name conflict. Also a question for @JasonB11: Should a file named "foo-foo bar-bar-bar1 5644.jpg" should just be moved to a directory named "foo-foo bar-bar-bar1" with its name unchanged, or also renamed to just "5644.jpg"?

Comment: We were thinking alike -- I'll update with the `-i`.

Comment: Another thing: this won't handle filenames that don't have spaces well at all (it'll try to create directories with the same name as the file). And another question for @JasonB11: should it operate on all .jpg files in this director *and all subdirectories*, or just those "right here" in this directory.

Comment: The "second extension" before the second space is how the directory should be named.\s\s
 -```/foo-foo bar-bar-bar1```

Comment: That is a good point. He explained that the files all had extensions separated by `spaces` not `'_'`, so that was the target. But if the filenames have no spaces, then he would need to key on `'.'` secondarily to insure there weren't a bunch of errors with directories and filenames being the same...

Comment: @JasonB11 - here is where I'm still confused. A filename only has ONE extension. In your comment, should the directory be `"foo-foo"`?

Comment: ```cc-19 a-15-1a 6767.jpg  
    cc-19 a-15-1a 6768.jpg  
    cc-19 a-15-1a 6769.jpg  
    cc-19 a-15-1a 6770.jpg  
    cc-19 a-15-1b 6781.jpg  
    cc-19 a-15-1b 6784.jpg  
    cc-19 a-15-1b 6787.jpg  
    cc-19 a-15-1b 6788.jpg  
    cc-19 a-18-1a    6790.jpg  
    cc-19 a-19-1e    6781.jpg```
  
ext1 = cc-19  
ext2 = a-xx-xx  \\this is what I need to use as the variable *I think..  
ext = meaningless

Comment: Or do you want `bar-bar-bar1`? You use the same *parameter expansions*, the only thing that changes is the order you apply them in (and the number of temp variables) **Bingo** -- you want `bar-bar-bar1`. Hold on, I'll update.

Comment: I still need the first part of the file name for the directory name.

"cc-19 a-15-1a"  :D

Comment: Oh, that was my 1st Answer `:)`

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer! @david-c-rankin this works. Thanks for helping me.

```
while read file; do
    fname="${file##*/}"   ## strip path information, leaving filename
    dname="${fname% *}"   ## get all chars before the last space
    dname="${dname%%* }"  ## trim ext 3 from filename
    mkdir -p "$dname"     ## create the directory (no error if it exists)
                          #  (add -i to be prompted if dir exists)
    mv -i "$file" "$dname"   ## move the file to the new directory
done < <(find . -type f -name "*.txt")
```

Comment: What happens if there is a file that has multiple spaces that are between the second and third extension? The script fails and returns this error ```mkdir: cannot create directory ‘’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot move './cc-19 11-12-r3     4482.txt' to '': No such file or directory```

Comment: The logic remains the same, but you just have more validation to do. If you can have any number of spaces in the filename. I would read all pieces of the filename into an array, e.g. `declare -a array;` then get rid of `dname="${dname%%* }"`, and then `idx=0; tmp="$dname"; while :; do array[$idx]="${tmp%% *}"; tmp="${tmp#* }"; ((idx++)); [ "${array[$((idx-1))]}" = "$tmp" ] && break; done` Then you know the number of pieces (e.g. `${#array[@]}`) so you use the pieces you want as the dir name.